# HTML Parser no Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, parser, xamarin.android

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo com o Xamarin com o intuito de efetuar *login* em uma conta web usando `HTTPWebRequest` e filtrar as informações relevantes do site para um aplicativo.

Já desenvolvi a parte de fazer *login*, agora preciso filtrar o HTML que tenho de retorno.

Eu preciso extrair do HTML a informação contida na decima segunda *tag* `<table>` do HTML, alguém saberia como fazer isso?

A grande dificuldade que tenho é que as *tags* não tem *ID* então não consigo usar isso.

o codigo html da pagina eu coloquei aqui para quem quiser copiar e me ajudar.
este html e retornado na string do response.

```
http://notepad.cc/share/hvptGOlmZQ
```

preciso das informacoes YYYY e XXXX contidas nas tables do html..

Comment: Você pode usar o [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Segundo [esse artigo do blog do Xamarin](http://blog.xamarin.com/data-extraction-in-mobile-apps/), ele dá conta de fazer isto. Sobre as *tags* não terem *IDs*, é possível extrair a informação da *tag* através da classe ou nome, vai depender da estrutura do HTML.

Comment: estou tentando usar ele mais nao parece ser facil como todos dizem , na verdade nao acho um tutorial util ate agora...

Comment: [Edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/60353/edit) a pergunta e coloque o HTML que você tem. Não esqueça de postar qual informação você quer extrair.

Comment: esta e a parte importante do html que preciso retirar.. preciso ler os valores dos XXXXX e dos YYYY

Answer (score 1):

Segundo o artigo [**Data Extraction in Mobile Apps**](http://blog.xamarin.com/data-extraction-in-mobile-apps/), o [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) pode ser utilizado para fazer isto.

> HtmlAgilityPack lhe permite analisar os documentos HTML. Ao contrário
>   de analisadores XML tradicionais, ele é capaz de se recuperar de
>   conteúdo mal escrito, muito parecido com o seu navegador web. Além
>   disso, a biblioteca é principalmente multi-plataforma, por isso é
>   fácil de criar seus projetos de móveis com Xamarin [...]

Supondo que o arquivo [*foo.html*](http://pastebin.com/zizg6a8E) contenha 20 tabelas e você queira selecionar somente a *décima segunda*, faça a consulta usando `//table[12]/tbody/tr/td//text()`. Segue um exemplo:

```
// using HtmlAgilityPack;

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("arquivoHTML.html");
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode nodo in 
   doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[2]/tbody/tr/td//text()")) {
       MessageBox.Show(nodo.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: supondo que haja 20 tables no html inteiro como eu pego a table exata que eu quero?

Comment: esse e o problema nao ha nada unico nela. Eu fazia isso com o beautifulSoup em python trazendo todas as tables para um vetor e lendo todos os nos dentro da table de posiçao 12

Comment: ta dando erro no foeach .. diz "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."

Comment: mesmo erro no mesmo lugar

Comment: Estranho, aqui no VS2012 funciona sem problemas, você referenciou o Html Agility Pack? veja se consegue compilar esse código (http://www.filedropper.com/windowsformsapplication6).

Comment: Funcionou, acredito que o erro deve ser que eu estou fazendo o doc.load(string) e nesta string contem um html ...

Comment: Na verdade nao, troquei para um arquivo html e continua com o mesmo erro, mas isso eu resolvo aqui, ja vi que funciona. obrigado

Comment: O erro que tava dando era que eu estava errando o caminho no selectNodes ... agora so falta acertar o caminho porem e muita informacao na pagina... mas vlw

Comment: editei a pergunta , coloquei o html inteiro. se puder me ver e me ajudar.. estou meio preso nisso, e esta maneira que vc colocou acima na resposta apesar de funcionar no c# nao funciona no xamarin... :/

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23267/discussion-between-user3896400-and-qmechanik).

Comment: coloquei o html inteiro da pagina pra ver se te ajuda , usei isso que vc colocou ai no xamarin mas aparentemente o xamarain trabalha de uma forma diferente o html agility Pack

Comment: @user3896400 Aqui o caminho `//table/tr/td//text()` funcionou, sem `tbody`, ([exemplo](http://www.filedropper.com/windowsformsapplication6_1)). Não tenho como testar no *Xamarin*, mas pelo que pesquisei, é necessário fazer alguns ajustes, dependerá do problema que você está tendo. [Aqui](https://github.com/Clancey/HtmlAgilityPack) parece haver uma versão do *HtmlAgilityPack* compatível com o *Xamarin*, olhe também [essa *thread*](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/680/get-html-code-and-text-inside-tags) para ver se te ajuda em algo. Não tenho como ajudar muito nessa situação.

Comment: @user3896400 Conseguiu resolver o problema? se sim, poste a solução para ajudar futuros visitantes com o mesmo problema. =)

Comment: nao consegui.... Acabei tendo que esquecer um pouco deste projeto .